# Spring Boot 3 with MVC JSP Support

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Is spring forgot to test MVC with jsp for 3.x? I tested in many ways. with 3.0.6 I'm testing currently. The jakarta.servlet is not recognizing any location of `.jsp` and `.html` as well.

following are the different error I got:

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'static/welcome.html' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'view/welcome.jsp' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'webapp/view/welcome.jsp' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Can anybody share the working example of code? I tried to add the javax servlet and jsp dependencies also. But still the jakarta is resolving the names.